# Two external 2K displays performance on 2020 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display

How is the performance going to be with two external (extend, not mirror) 2k displays on the 2020 MacBook pro?

It is the 13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbols 3 ports MacBook pro with 16GB RAM and Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 1536 MB.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to AD. This question is somewhat opinion-based (what is good performance?) and definitely needs more detail regarding your workload. If you browse the web. Learn more here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: 8GB or 16GB RAM?

Comment: 16GB [more text]